# Mysql joins headache

Tags: mysql, left-join

[image]

I have this database. It does not contain all the tables, but for my problem what is included in the picture is enough.

The database is designed for transportation companies.

So, I have a booking. Any booking can have multiple addresses. These types are (routing_type: pick-up, stop, drop-off). My addresses are either a street address or an airport.

Inside routing table is use either the address_id or the airport_id to tell which type the routing is. If airport_id has a number than address_id is NULL.

In my booking_routing table I have as many entries as there are routing types for a specific booking. If I have 3 addresses for a specific booking, I will have 3 entries in booking_routing (maybe Pick-up, then Stop and then Drop-off). Usually there are only two addresses necessary, pick-up an drop-off.

**PROBLEM: I try to create a query in which I will have displayed my Pick-up and Drop-off point on the same line with other fields from the booking.**

Example:

Booking_ID   Account_ID   ...   Pick-Up       Drop-Off
121             32                      1 Main St           IAD, AA-322

Right now I only managed to get them using LEFT JOIN on two lines. 
Like this:
Booking_ID   Account_ID   ...   Address_Type       Address
121             32                        Pick_up           1 Main St
121             32                        Drop-Off           IAD, AA-322

```
SELECT   
b.booking_id as ID, a.account_id as Acc_ID, 
MAX(CASE WHEN br.routing_type_id = 1 THEN -- 1=pick-up
    Concat(ad.address_line1, " ", api.code, " ", aii.code, "-", ap.flight_number) END) as Pick_up,
    MAX(CASE WHEN br.routing_type_id = 4 THEN  -- 4=drop-off
             Concat(ad.address_line1, " ", api.code, " ", aii.code, "-", ap.flight_number) END) as Drop_off

FROM booking b
left JOIN account a ON b.account_id = a.account_id
left join booking_routing br ON b.booking_id = br.booking_id
left join routing r ON br.routing_id = r.routing_id
left join routing_type rt ON br.routing_type_id = rt.routing_type_id
left join address ad ON r.address_id = ad.address_id
left join airport ap ON r.airport_id = ap.airport_id
left join airport_info api ON ap.airport_info_id = api.airport_info_id
left join airline_info aii ON ap.airline_info_id = aii.airline_info_id

group by b.booking_id, a.account_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `MAX` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT Booking_Id, 
   Account_Id, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN Address_Type = 'Pick_up' THEN Address END) Pick_Up,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Address_Type = 'Drop-Off' THEN Address END) Drop_Off
FROM YourTables...
GROUP BY Booking_Id, Account_Id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf3c8/2)

Comment: @Cristian -- can you clarify -- seems to work for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf3c8/2 -- if you can supply your query, then perhaps I could help more.

Comment: I added the code that I am using and it's still not working in my case. On the code you made it's working but not on my end. Don't know what is going on.

Comment: @Cristian -- perhaps you'd be better off using your results (which had the 2 lines) and wrap that in a subquery, and then run the MAX/CASE.  If you could build a SQL Fiddle which returns those 2 records, I'd be happy to look at it.  Best.

Comment: After many tries I finally managed to get the needed results. It worked without the subquery and then running max/case. It did not work at first because I was using a wrong field. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing. I am trying to understand how the MAX/CASE works. Can you help me understand that a little or maybe point me to a link?